# LINQ OR operator not giving result

Tags: c#, linq

I have written a LINQ query with or condition in it, but its not working, it seem I am doing something wrong.

I am passing a string value and on it, I want to get my result.

```
var userDetails = context.tbl_members.Where
                (
                  d => d.Mobile == value 
                  || 
                  d.MemberId == Int32.Parse(value)
                ).SingleOrDefault();
```

its not working if someone put a mobile no, but if work with memberID

if I split the query keep only mobile no its running fine.

```
var userDetails = context.tbl_members.Where(d => d.Mobile == value ).SingleOrDefault();
```

Please check what I did wrong with or condition

Regards
Moksha

Comment: Define "not working" - does it throw an exception? Not return the results you wanted? What? Also: what are the **exact** database data types involved here? A "char(20)" would behave very differently to a "nvarchar(20)" for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var userDetails = context.tbl_members
                         .Where(d => d.Mobile == value || 
                                     d.MemberId == Int32.Parse(value))
                         .SingleOrDefault();
```

It looks like you are using Linq to Entities or Linq to Sql. `Int32.Parse()` is not supported in that context - just do the number conversion before your query:

```
int numValue = Int32.Parse(value);
var userDetails = context.tbl_members
                         .Where(d => d.Mobile == value || d.MemberId == numValue)
                         .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help brokenGlass,

the error was in converting from string to int, as I was passing string of 10 digits, it was not getting converted into int

Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

thanks